# am charts json from field to field

Tags: php, json, amcharts

Part of the script says from field to field which is to do with this. Here's my JSON pulling info from my database, value 1 is amount, value 2 is time

```
[{
  "date": "2014-12-09",
  "value1": 367,
  "value2": 03:06:00
}, {
  "date": "2014-12-09",
  "value1": 367,
  "value2": 03:06:00
}]
```

That's my data, this is part of the script that wants me to map it? :S

```
        dataSet.fieldMappings = [{
            fromField: "valu1",
            toField: "value2"
        }, {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }];
```

I only have 3 fields don't I? Sorry for a vague question, I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The fieldMapping maps the JSON-fields with the valueField specified in the graph-properties.

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
[{
  "date": "2014-12-09 03:06:00",
  "value": 367
}, {
  "date": "2014-12-09 03:07:00",
  "value": 673
}]
```

Note that i put the time into the date-field and changed the second date and value to be different from the first. (I think two similar datapoints won't work)

For this dataset your mapping should look like this:

```
dataSet.fieldMappings = [{
    fromField: "value", // this is the JSON-field
    toField: "valueMapped" // the graph will search for this field - see below
}];
```

To find the data, the graph needs to know the mapped field:

```
"graphs": [{
    "valueField": "valueMapped"
}];
```

Now one last step for the correct use of the "date"-field:

```
"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
"categoryField": "date"
```